# how to re-initialize asyntask and volley request

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-volley

I am currently performing a network check (wifi or data service) on an asyntask and it works fine but when ever the task is executed more than ones my application crashes and generates this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
```

Same goes for my volley request....when ever a request is unsuccessful and i retry it by clicking a button my application crashes and throws an exception stating `request has already been executed`.

Please guys how do i re-initialize or remove a request/task to prevent such errors.

Alternatively can anyone suggest how i can solve this problem.

This question doesn't contain any code because my AsynTask and volley request are work except the exception generated when i retry a task or request.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you performing a network check in an `AsyncTask`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute the same AsyncTask twice.  You have to create a new AsyncTask of the same type and execute that instead.